# Aero themes aren't activated on Sony VAIO running Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, sony-vaio, aero

I have a Sony VAIO laptop SVE15111EN with Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit running. The Aero themes are not activated. The troubleshooter says

> The current video card may support Aero with a driver that is compliant with the Windows Display Driver Model (WDDM).  Contact the manufacturer of your computer or video card for a WDDM-compatible driver.

I can't find any relevant driver for Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit for my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Finally after a bit of searching i found the right drivers. I have a intel processor b9700 processor.. the drivers are on the link:

http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=21429&lang=eng